# How to get parent id when creating a child ember js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I want to set parent_id in child records.

My models are Recipe (id, title) and Ingredients(id, about, recipe_id).

I have a form where i create recipe with many ingredients. All works well but i don't know how to set a parent_id in child records after parent record is created.

**Example:**

We create recipe (id = 1, title = 'Title01'). So all our ingredients will have field recipe_id with 1 (id=2, about='this is ingredient', recipe_id=1)

recipe.js.coffee

```
App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  ingredients: DS.hasMany('App.Ingredient')
```

ingredient.js.coffee

```
App.Ingredient = DS.Model.extend
  about: DS.attr('string')
  recipe: DS.belongsTo('App.Recipe')
```

new.emblem (here i create parent Recipe and children Ingredients)

```
h1 Create recipe

form
  div
    label{bindAttr for='title.elementId'} Title
    Ember.TextField valueBinding='title' name='title' viewName='title'

  div
    label{bindAttr for='about.elementId'} About
    Ember.TextArea valueBinding='about' name='about' viewName='about'

  #ingredients
    h3 Ingredients
    each ingredient in content.ingredients itemViewClass='App.ItemView'
      h3= this.view.rebasedIndex
      .control-group
        .controls
          Ember.TextField valueBinding='ingredient.about'
          a{ action removeIngredient ingredient target='controller' } href='#' Remove
    div
      a{ action addIngredient target='controller' } href='#' Add Ingredient

  button.btn.btn-success{ action save this } Create
  button.btn.btn-inverse{ action cancel this } Cancel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know coffee script, but could you just create a parentIdBinding for each ingredient view?

EDIT providing an example:

```
{{#each recipe in recipes}}
    {{#each ingredient in ingredients}}
        {{view ingredientView parentBinding="recipe"}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: can you give me an example how to do this? on js or coffee it doesn't matter.